# Upload multiple images toserver using volley too slow

Tags: java, android

I want to upload multiple images to server with volley request, I know that multiple base64 encoded images too large to upload, nut I need any suggestions to solve my problem, when upload 5 images with other parameter and request take long time and progress dialogue freezing and no response, when refresh my network in my device the request complete successfully, I dont know what is the problem, is the speed of network or thecsize of images or what? please help

I am using photoutil library to get image from gallery and send to server

```
final String encodedString = ImageBase64.encode(bitmap);
            final String encodedString2 = ImageBase64.encode(bitmap2);
            final String encodedString3 = ImageBase64.encode(bitmap3);
            final String encodedString4 = ImageBase64.encode(bitmap4);
            final String encodedString5 = ImageBase64.encode(bitmap5);
```

volley string request policy

```
   stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                                0,
                                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                                 DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
                        requestQueue2 = Volley.newRequestQueue(academy_registration.this);

                        requestQueue2.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: How slow exactly? Like 5 minutes? And what size of images?

Comment: 9 minutes and sometimes progress dialogue not stop for long long time, the size of each image about 150kb

Comment: That's too long for 150kb images. Sounds like you app (or device) has limited amount of network connections, so it wait's for available one. `Volley` should allow to log network requests, so I would add log messages and see exactly when and what starts. That might give some thoughts.